# How are matchings a lower bound for an approximate vertex cover?

Tags: approximation, matching

I am reading *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al and they mention maximal matchings as approximations for vertex cover.

They mention that the 2-approximation ratio is a lower bound. How is a maximal matching a lower bound? Does it mean that it is the lowest approximation value we can get compared to $\log n$ of the greedy algorithm that is polynomial?

The images below show the optimal vertex cover = 8 but and a maximal matching of 12.

[image: Maximal matching in Dasgupta]

I decided to find another matching which I later discovered is called a maximum matching from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)). Since a maximum matching is also a maximal matching, I assume that this the worst that we can get, a maximum matching of 16 vertices.

[image: Maximum matching]

How can one improve on the edges picked then? My 16 vertices versus the book's 12?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a maximal matching, that is, $M$ is a matching which is not contained in a larger matching. Note that $M$ need not be a maximum matching, which is a matching of maximal size.

If $M$ contains $m$ edges, then:

1. Any vertex cover contains at least $m$ vertices. 
   This is because any vertex covers at most one edge of the matching.
2. There exists a vertex cover containing $2m$ vertices, namely, all vertices of the matching. 
    Indeed, if the vertices of the matching $M$ do not form a vertex cover, then there is some edge $e$ which is not covered by the vertices of $M$, and so $M$ is contained in the larger matching $M \cup \{e\}$, contradicting the definition of $M$.